# Why is Groovy evaluator returning NULL?

Tags: groovy, nullpointerexception, evaluate

I have the following code:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("story", storyFactory.newStory());
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);
exp = getExpression();
System.out.println("Expression: " + exp);
Object result = (Object)shell.evaluate(exp);
```

That produces the following NullPointerException and console output:

```
Expression: story.getDescriptions().get(0).setText(story.getDescriptions().get(0).getText().replace("@", "at").replace("\"", "'").replace("%", "percent"));
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.me.myapp.GroovyEvaluator._evaluate(GroovyEvaluator.java:56)
    at com.me.myapp.testing.expressions.Driver.runEvaluator(Driver.java:131)
    at com.me.myapp.testing.expressions.Driver.run(Driver.java:65)
    at com.me.myapp.testing.expressions.Driver.main(Driver.java:31)

null
```

Why is `result` NULL? It can't be a problem with the `story` instance, as I have verified in other code that `getDescriptions()` and `getDescriptions().get(0)` both return non-null values. Also, `getDescriptions().get(0)` does return a non-null, non-empty String value. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the value of:

```
story.getDescriptions().get(0).setText
```

I assume `setText` has a `void` return type

Therefore you get `null`

Try changing your expression to:

```
story.descriptions.get( 0 ).with { d ->
    d.text = d.text.replace("@", "at")
                   .replace( '"', "'")
                   .replace( "%", "percent" )
    d
}
```

(or all on one line like):

```
story.descriptions.get( 0 ).with { d -> d.text = d.text.replace("@", "at").replace( '"', "'").replace( "%", "percent" ) ; d }
```

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates (+1) - however now I'm getting a different error: `startup failed, Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: d @ line 1, column 119.
1 error`. Any idea why it can't recognize `d`? Do I need to add `d` as a bound variable in the `binding`? Thanks again!

Comment: @TicketMonster Added a version on one line with a semi-colon before the final `d`...  Does that work?